# get this error on request post (TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined (line 12, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, http-post

I get this error when I request post

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined (line 12, file "Code")
```

i used it befor and it worked correctly but now i have error
this is my code:

```
function doGet(e) {
 return ManageSheet(e);
}
function doPost(e) {
 return ManageSheet(e);
}

function ManageSheet(e) {
var e = JSON.stringify(e);
Logger.log(e)
 //READ ALL RECORDS
 
 if ( e.parameter.func == "ReadAll") {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sh = ss.getSheets()[parseInt(e.parameter.SN)-1]; 
   var rg = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); 
   var outString = '';
     for(var row=0 ; row<rg.length ; ++row){
       outString += rg[row].join(',') + '\n';  
     } 
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(outString).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
 }
  
 //CREATE NEW RECORD  
 if (e.parameter.func == "Create") {
   
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   
   var sh = ss.getSheets()[parseInt(e.parameter.SN)-1];
   
   var data =[Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3:30", "MM/dd/yyyy"),Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "HH:mm:ss"),e.parameter.A, e.parameter.B, e.parameter.C, e.parameter.D, e.parameter.E, e.parameter.F, e.parameter.G, e.parameter.H, e.parameter.I, e.parameter.J, e.parameter.K, e.parameter.L, e.parameter.M, e.parameter.N, e.parameter.O, e.parameter.P,e.parameter.Q, e.parameter.R, e.parameter.S, e.parameter.T, e.parameter.U, e.parameter.V, e.parameter.W, e.parameter.X, e.parameter.Y, e.parameter.Z]; 
   
   sh.appendRow(data);
   
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(data);
 
 }
 
}
```

i deployed it as webapp and this is my web app [link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzXUJMWgI0S-F6G6n0_59oUp8XlnRWwg8Fr16fYyAu4u3wsxS_eaK3iM3OpmJPVHYxb/exec)

I used link like this in browser and get an error

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzXUJMWgI0S-F6G6n0_59oUp8XlnRWwg8Fr16fYyAu4u3wsxS_eaK3iM3OpmJPVHYxb/exec?username=jsmith&age=21&func=Create&SN=1&A=df
```

could you please help me?

Comment: It's very likely that you haven't created a new version for the last changes.

Comment: thank you @Ruben, i checked it. it is not working yet

Comment: @MostafaKarami I don't see `e.parameter` or `func` defined in what you have shared, is that variable defined in another script, another function or library?